# Redirect with matched parameters with react-router-dom doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom:4.3.0-rc.3` .
The route component

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect from='/p/:userId' to='/p/:userId/main' />
  <Route path="/p/:userId/main" component={Main} />
</Switch>
```

when I get a url `/p/123456` it redirect to `/p/:userId/main` and lost userId .
I am confused about this.In official site, i can't get the answer.

Answer (score 4):

A `<Redirect>` doesn't do any pattern compiling. You have to give it the actual URI that you want to redirect to.

The approach that I would take would be to use a `<Route>` instead of a `<Redirect>` for the matching, and then use the parsed param to build the redirect URI.

```
<Route path="/p/:userId" render={({ match }) => (
  <Redirect to={`${match.url}/main`} />
)} />
```